# Select2 Ajax not filtering results based on query

Tags: jquery-select2

I am new to Select2 and am having trouble integrating AJAX. When I search, the results aren't being filtered based on the query.

Here's how it looks: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q8mjM.png  - The right characters are underlined in the results, but nothing is filtered out. In my non-ajax Select2 and in the examples I've seen, the filtering seems to happen somewhat automatically, so I am hesitant to write a custom filter as there is probably a better one built in already.

Here's my code:

```
<script>
  $("#search_bar").select2({
    placeholder: "Search for another Concept",
    minimumInputLength: 1,
    ajax: { // instead of writing the function to execute the request we use Select2's convenient helper
      url: "/concepts/names_for_search",
      dataType: 'json',
      data: function (term, page) {
        return {
        q: term, // search term
        page: page
         };
      },
      results: function (data, page) {
        return { results: data};
      }
    },
  });
</script>
```

Also, here is an example of my JSON:

```
[{"id":1,"text":"Limits"},{"id":2,"text":"Derivatives"},{"id":3,"text":"One-Sided Limits"},{"id":4,"text":"Formal Definition of a limit"}]
```

Any ideas? Hopefully I am just doing something stupid and it is a quick fix. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: I too wish there was a better way to do this! I don't find it intuitive to go to server just to do filtering, if I have all the rows already with me!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You will need to write a custom filter on server side to filter the results. What you type in the box is saved in 'term' and then 'q' is sent as a request parameter with the ajax call. So the ajax call to
url:"/concepts/names_for_search?q=deri"
should only return the filtered results and not all the results.

**Update**
Select2 will make an AJAX call every time you type in the search box. You have to filter the results on server side and then return the results based on the text in search box.
I am using it in my JSP/Servlet application as below

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException  
{
    String searchTerm = request.getParameter("q");

    String json = getOptions(searchTerm);
    //getOptions method will return a string of  in JSON format
    //[{"id":"1","name":"Derivatives"}]
    response.getWriter().write(json);
}
```

Your JavaScript code is correct.

I found Select2 is used [here](http://www.indiewebseries.com). If you open the link http://www.indiewebseries.com/search?q=ind and http://www.indiewebseries.com/search?q=in the results obtained are different and based on the 'q' parameter.
While in you case, the results for calls to url '/concepts/names_for_search?q=d' and '/concepts/names_for_search?q=deri' are the same(i.e. not filtered)

Comment: Hey Thanks and sorry this response is so late. Is there any way to just re-use their filter as if I weren't doing AJAX (maybe copy/pasting from their source code)? Also, do you know of any examples you could point me to? Light-googling has turned up surprisingly little. Thanks a lot for your help - once I am able to upvote people, you'll definitely get one.

Answer (score 3):

This question was asked on the github project and the answer was: filter on the server side. 
The default filter function called when AJAX is not used is present in the Select2 documentation on the `matcher` parameter:

```
function(term, text) { return text.toUpperCase().indexOf(term.toUpperCase())>=0; }
```