# Names Picker using Select2 and REST Service control

Tags: xpages, jquery-select2

I'm trying to create a Names Picker using Select2, for this I want to pull data from ($VIMPeople) View by using a REST Service.

The problem I have is that I need to filter my JSON source based on user input also I need to figure out how to pull new entries since If I don't set the 'Count' property from REST Service, it will get only the first 10 entries by default.

This is how it looks based on this code; the right characters are underlined in the results, but nothing is filtered out.

[image]

```
<xp:br></xp:br>
Names Picker using REST Service
<xp:br></xp:br>
<xp:inputHidden id="inputHidden1" />
<xp:scriptBlock id="scriptBlock1">
    <xp:this.value><![CDATA[
            x$( "#{id:inputHidden1}" ).select2({
                        placeholder: "Find someone",
                        minimumInputLength: 2,
                        allowClear : true,
                        quietMillis: 300,
                        width: '300px',
                        multiple: true,
                        ajax: {
                            dataType: 'json',
                            url: "./NamesPickerSelect2.xsp/namespicker",                             
                            //results: function (data) {
                            //  return {results: data};
                            //}
                            data: function (term, page) {
                                return {
                                    q: term, // search term                                     
                                    page: page
                                };
                            },
                            results: function (data, page) {
                                return { results: data};
                            }
                        }
                    });
            ]]></xp:this.value>
</xp:scriptBlock>
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15232476/select2-ajax-not-filtering-results-based-on-query?rq=1 Also, have a look at Domino Access Services documentation http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/xpAPIViewer.xsp?lookupName=IBM+Domino+Access+Services+9.0.1#action=openDocument&res_title=Viewfolder_entries_GET_dds10&content=apicontent

Comment: What does the JSON look like that is returned by the ajax call to ./NamesPickerSelect2.xsp/namespicker? Is it the standard readViewEntries&outputformat=json?

Comment: @keithstric, the result is displayed under my sample print screen under Response section.

Comment: I can't see that screen shot unfortunately.

Comment: @keithstric, for example: `[
  {
      "@entryid":"2001-83EECF8CC1C25E06852579E30076055D",
      "@unid":"83EECF8CC1C25E06852579E30076055D",
      "id":"Simbles",
      "text":"George Simbles\/USW\/Acme"
  },
  {
      "@entryid":"2002-468F9B8E1E6127468525791C0039471B",
      "@unid":"468F9B8E1E6127468525791C0039471B",
      "id":"Assefa",
      "text":"Gera Assefa\/Bos\/Acme"
  },
  {
      "@entryid":"2003-1A7821539ACBB07505257AB700648F86",
      "@unid":"1A7821539ACBB07505257AB700648F86",
      "id":"Johnson",
      "text":"Gerald Johnson\/USW\/Acme"
  }
]`

Answer (score 2):

OK, looking at this, I would recommend ditching the REST service and just using the readviewentries&outputformat=json url. This way you don't have to manage finding the search term in the view and iterating through the results building JSON as you go. Not to mention, it's very fast. Using the readViewEntries&outputFormat=json you should get back a JSON string like:

```
{
"@timestamp": "20140114T211303,12Z",
"@toplevelentries": "6",
"viewentry": [{
    "@position": "1",
    "@unid": "309784A4BC62956E85257BEC0007BE7A",
    "@noteid": "1F5E",
    "@siblings": "6",
    "entrydata": [{
        "@columnnumber": "0",
        "@name": "$1",
        "text": {
            "0": "Demo User1/REDPILL"
        }
    },
    {
        "@columnnumber": "1",
        "@name": "$0",
        "text": {
            "0": "Demo"
        }
    },
    {
        "@columnnumber": "2",
        "@name": "$2",
        "text": {
            "0": ""
        }
    },
    {
        "@columnnumber": "3",
        "@name": "$3",
        "text": {
            "0": "User1"
        }
    },
    {
        "@columnnumber": "4",
        "@name": "$4",
        "text": {
            "0": "CN=Demo User1/O=REDPILL"
        }
    },
    {
        "@columnnumber": "5",
        "@name": "Comment",
        "text": {
            "0": ""
        }
    }]
}]
}
```

Going this route takes out quite a bit of the complexity and labor of creating your own REST service. So below is how I'm handling this sort of request:

```
var inputField = $("[id$=inputField1]");
inputField.select2({
    allowClear: true,
    openOnEnter: false,
    minimumInputLength: 2,
    width: '300px',
    placeHolder: "Find Someone",
    /**
     * Assign an ID to the selected item if one doesn't exist in the data
     * @param{Object} object - A single element from the http GET request
     * @return{String} - The ID of the element
     */
    id: function(object) {
       return object.entrydata[3].text[0]; 
    },
    /*
     * This is basically the jQuery ajax function
     */
    ajax: {
        url: "http://server/names.nsf/$(VIMPeople)?readViewEntries&outputFormat=json",
        dataType: "json",
        /**
         * @param{String} term - The term search for
         * @param{Number} page - The number of pages to return?
         */
        data: function(term, page) {
            /*
             * The items you place in the return object will get added onto the query url like:
             * &startkey=term&count=10
             */
            return {
                startkey: term, 
                count: 10
            };
        },
        /**
         * @param{Object} data - The results of the url GET request
         * @param{Number} page - The page number of the result?
         * @return{Array} the array within the json which contains the result objects
         */
        results: function(data, page) {
            /*
             * Specifiy the property within the data object which contains the array of items
             */
            return {results: data.viewentry};
        }
    },
    /**
     * Formats the items in the selection list
     * @param{Object} object - a single entry from the viewentry array which was returned
     *      from the GET request
     * @param container{jQuery Object} - wrapper of the node that contains the result
     * @param{Object} query - The query object used to request this set of results
     * @return{String} a jQuery or html element that will represent each item in the selection
     *      list
     */
    formatResult: function(object, container, query) {
       var selectionItem = "<div class='select2-user-result'>" + object.entrydata[0].text[0] + "</div>"; 
    },
    /**
     * This formats the selection value
     * @param{Object} object - a single entry from the viewentry array which was selected
     * @param{jQuery Object} container - wrapper of the node that contains the result
     * @return{String} The value to return when an item is selected, return lastname
     */
    formatSelection: function(object, container) {
        return object.entrydata[3].text[0];
    },
    /**
     * This sets the value of the select2 item upon initialization. It uses the value to do another
     * lookup to get an object that formatSelection can use to render the value
     * @param{jQueryArray} element - the dom element of the field select2 is attached to
     * @param{function} callback - The function which will pass the results to formatSelection function
     */
    initSelection: function(element) {
        var searchTerm = element.val();
        $.ajax("http://server/names.nsf/$(VIMPeople)?readViewEntries&outputFormat=json", {
            data: {
                startkey: searchTerm,
                count: 1
            },
            dataType: "json"
        }).done(function(data) {
            var entry = data.viewentry[0]
            callback(entry);
        });
    }
});
```

That should get what you're looking for. You may have to change the formatSelection and formatResult methods to suit your needs.

Comment: great suggestion, however, I'm having problems with formatSelection and formatResult (newbie using this plugin). I'm getting FullName by changing `object.entrydata[0].text[0]` within formatselection. But, I see blanks under list box selection. The only issue I see with this workaround is that your are using startkey and partial match within the Full Name doesn't work.

Comment: For those who see blank selections in the select2 list, in the "formatResult", make sure to add "return selectionItem" to the function.

Answer (score 1):

After looking at keithsric answer, he pointed me on how I can filter my result dynamically; so I tried using **search** argument within my url.

This seems to work as well (I need to try it out more)

```
<xp:scriptBlock id="scriptBlock1">
    <xp:this.value><![CDATA[
            x$( "#{id:inputHidden1}" ).select2({
                        placeholder: "Find someone",
                        minimumInputLength: 2,
                        allowClear : true,
                        quietMillis: 300,
                        width: '300px',
                        multiple: true,
                        ajax: {
                            dataType: 'json',
                            url: "./NamesPickerSelect2.xsp/namespicker",
                            data: function (term, page) {
                                return {
                                    search:'[fullname=]*'+term+'*',
                                    q: term // search term                                      
                                //  page: page                                      
                                };
                            },
                            results: function (data, page) {
                                return { results: data};
                            }
                        }
                    });
            ]]></xp:this.value>
</xp:scriptBlock>
```

[image: This is how it looks]