# Select2 filter not working

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, jquery-select2

I use Select2 to handle my dropdownmenu.
The dropdownmenu get's populated via "Ajax-call" to PHP, who get's data from Mysql.

The Select2 dropdownmenu offers serach function and filtering.
When i type in something in the search field, the letters get underlined, but the filter doesn't work.
So the list won't get filtered by the letters i type in. Why?

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#test").select2({
placeholder: "test",
minimumInputLength: 1,
ajax: {
    url: "test.php",
    dataType: 'json',
    //search term
    data: function (term, page) {
        return {
        q: term, // search term
        page: page
        };
    },
    results: function (data, page) {
    return { results: data};
    } //End of results
}, //End of Ajax
}); //End of select2
```

Comment: does select tag gets filled with data from ajax call anyways? you can check it with developer tools?

Comment: @George I do not really understand your question. The dropdownmenu gets filled with data from mysql yes! How can i check it with tool?

Comment: OK if it's filled then not ajax problem

Comment: You know the fact that when using ajax and need filtering it will send new request to the server, and will not filter locally, so you should do filtering on the server side: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15232476/select2-ajax-not-filtering-results-based-on-query

Comment: As you are sending `term` to server side, you should filter your data on that basis & then return the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The filtering must be done in server-side.
This PHP script will make the filtering work.

PHP:

```
<?php
// setup databse connection
require_once('db.php'); 

// Select from database, i have set the limit to 40 to speed up results
$result = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM table WHERE option LIKE :term ORDER BY option ASC LIMIT 0,40");

// bind the value for security with the wildcard % attached.
$result->bindvalue(':term','%'.$_GET["q"].'%',PDO::PARAM_STR);
$result->execute();

// make sure there are some results else a null query will be returned
if($result->rowcount() != 0) {
while($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $answer[] = array(
                    "id"=>$row['option_id'],
                    "text"=>$row['option']);
// the text I want to show is in the form of option
}
} else {
// 0 results send a message back to say so.
$answer[] = array("id"=>"0","text"=>"No Results Found..");
}

// finally encode the answer to json and send back the result.
echo json_encode($answer);
```